# Ivy Coils Around

Tags: verb-forms, participles

I have a question about the usage of the verb "*coil*".  Could I use the present tense of "*coil*" to describe the present state of ivy coiled around something?

Could I write this:

> Ivy ***coils*** around the column.

to mean the current state of ivy that is coiled (adjective state) around some column?

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Comment: In general, yes... except (assuming the ivy isn't actively in the process of coiling), it would usually be "coiled". *The ivy was coiled around the column.*

Comment: @Catija If the ivy is alive and growing, then it *is* actively in the state of coiling, but yeah, that would probably be a more common phrasing.

Comment: @DCShannon I meant, in the sense of a magical vine that was growing while you watched it. In general, the coiling would have happened months before or longer. :)

Comment: @Catija It doesn't have to be magical. They grow while you watch them, just slowly. Here's a [time lapse of a vine growing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTljaIVseTc). They coil as they grow.

Comment: @DCShannon  So, the present tense "*coils*" should be used for the act of "*coiling*", not the state of "*coiled*" around the column?

Comment: @meatie Yes, basically. It just so happens that living vines are technically in the act of coiling.

Comment: @DCShannon  Yet, the present tense of "*stretch*" in "*the vine* ***stretches*** *across the field*" or "*the path* ***stretches*** *along the coast*" seems fine even when the state-sense, not the action-sense, is intended.

Comment: I actually believe that "The ivy coils/ed around the column" would be perfect in descriptive speech! If you wanted to make it even more descriptive, you could maybe say "The ivy slithered around the column" to add personification! *Sorry for that, I got a bit carried away!*

Comment: @meatie: "the snake coils around its prey" and "the ivy coils around the column".  Coiling is what they *do*, not what they *are doing now*, However, in certain *narrative*  (storytelling) styles, the simple present can be used instead of the continuous for rhetorical effect.

Comment: @meatie I think it depends on the word a little. 'Stretches' is more commonly used to describe a thing that is stretched than some similar words. I found no definition of 'coils' which included the idea of 'being coiled'. However, look at definition #6 of [strech from Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stretch#English): (intransitive) To extend physically, especially from limit point to limit point. *The beach stretches from Cresswell to Amble.*

Comment: @DCShannon  So, "*Ivy* ***coils*** *around the column*" is not as natural sounding as "*a path* ***stretches*** *across the field*"?

Comment: @meatie As I said before, the ivy ***is*** coiling, so that sounds totally fine. I came up with another example: "The rubble piles in the corner." "The rubble is piled in the corner." The first is no good at all.

Comment: @DCShannon  If I change "ivy" to "rope", would "*rope* ***coils*** *around the column*" be good English?

Comment: That would be grammatically correct as well, but not a good way to describe rope that has previously been coiled around a column. I think your question is mostly about tense. Did you really want to ask about 'coil', or was it just an example word? Could probably try and write an answer at some point here, just want to make sure the question is phrased the way you want before I answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is grammatically correct, and it is not an unusual usage at all.  Using present tense in this way is often done when describing the current appearance of a building or landscape.  As such, you'll primarily see it in writing describing the essence of a location or in real estate advertisements.

> The ivy coils around the columns on the front porch, and the wide French doors connect a broad green lawn filled with children to a kitchen filled with the scents of baking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is grammatically correct.

It does sounds strange to use ivy as subject with an active verb though. It would be more natural to say the ivy is coiling or the ivy is coiled. Unless you're say writing an essay about about ivy, and you are really interested in the ivy more than anything else.

Comment: I don't agree that it sounds strange; ivy may not be the most speedy actor but it does grow and move over time.